# HTML5 paste event doesn't contain more than a single file

Tags: javascript, html, paste

I'm trying to handle paste event and get the files that are pasted with Javascript as it follows:

```
const pasteHandler = (e => {
  const { items: files } = e.clipboardData;
  console.log(files.length); // this maximally contains two elements on Chromium-based browsers.
                             // One of which is text, and the other one is a file.

  const parsedFiles = [];
  for( let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const file = files[i].getAsFile();
    if (file !== null)
      parsedFiles.push(file);
  }

  // do stuff with parsedFiles;
});

container.addEventListener('paste', pasteHandler);

// and later dispose the event handler
container.removeEventListener('paste', pasteHandler);
```

I was expecting the `.items` to contain all the files that I paste, not just a single parsable file. I check the `ClipboardEvent`'s official docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent) and it says this is an experimental feature. I am wondering if I'm missing something or is it expected? Plus, on Firefox 75, I can not intercept any files at all.

Comment: On Chrome 83. Pasting a file doesn't work at all for me. `items` is always empty. Text works fine.

Comment: @MoritzRoessler strange, I'm using the same version of Chrome but I do get a single file when I paste it.